# Соединение двух компьютеров (с динамическим ip) на C++ кросплатформено

Tags: сеть, qt, c++

Как это сделать? Можно ли это сделать с помощью Qt? Не откажусь от ссылок и любой другой информации по этой теме.

Comment: И оба под NAT-ом? :)

Comment: @avp а проброс портов через шлюз (redirecting) не поможет?

Comment: Если IP роутера сервера известен во "внешнем" мире, то поможет.

Только автоматизировать проброс самой программой задача не самая простая.

Comment: да надо будет писать серверную часть